# Is it possible to make a "timebomb" in java with this code I used?

Tags: java, timer

So I made a timer but now I want that when the timer gets to 0 to print out "boom" how do I do this?

```
public class Main {

    static Thread thread = new Thread();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 60;i>=0;i--) {
            thread.sleep(1000L);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just adding System.out.println("Boom"); after (not inside) the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
static Thread thread = new Thread();
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    for(int i = 60;i>=0;i--)
    {
        thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println("boom");
}
```

Comment: This works (sort of), but `Thread.sleep()` is a static method, so the creation of an instance (and subsequent calling of `sleep()` on that instance) is both unnecessary and horribly misleading.

Comment: True, there are many ways of doing this - but thought that I would just continue the code in the original post as requested above. Many better ways.